# Setting up Social business toolkit SBT database using extension library

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I am trying to configure the connections vcard. I have done a change in the proxy-config.properties as per the [document](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=Lotus%20Connections%203%20documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Configuring_the_Communities_business_card_on_a_Domino_server_lc3&content=pdcontent).But I  get following error.
[image]

Can somebody tell me what  is missing?

Regards,

Prashant

Comment: Have you setup the web security store? http://heidloff.net/home.nsf/dx/12152011034545AMNHECAP.htm

Comment: Thanks, Thats missing in my setup. I will add it and give it a go.

Comment: Let me know if it helped. I have created an answer based on my comment

Answer (score 1):

Have you setup the web security store as required?
See http://heidloff.net/home.nsf/dx/12152011034545AMNHECAP.htm for more information.